# React custom hooks taking dynamic data properties

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-hooks

So I've read these blog posts about using custom hooks to fetch data, so for instance we have a custom hook doing the API call, setting the data, possible errors as well as the spinny isFetching boolean:

```
export const useFetchTodos = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
      setIsFetching(true);
      axios.get('api/todos')
        .then(response => setData(response.data)
        .catch(error => setError(error.response.data)
        .finally(() => setFetching(false);
      }, []);
     return {data, isFetching, error};
}
```

And then at the top level of our component we would just call `const { data, error, fetching } = useFetchTodos();` and all great we render our component with all the todos fetched.

The thing I don't understand is how would we send dynamic data / parameters to the hook based on the internal state of the component, without breaking the rules of hooks?

For instance, imagine we have a `useFetchTodoById(id)` hook defined the same way as the above one, how would we pass that `id` around? Let's say our `TodoList` component which renders our Todos is the following:

```
export const TodoList = (props) => {
    const [selectedTodo, setSelectedTodo] = useState();
    
    useEffect(() => {
      useFetchTodoById(selectedTodo.id) --> INVALID HOOK CALL, cannot call custom hooks from useEffect, 
        and also need to call our custom hooks at the "top level" of our component
    }, [selectedTodo]);

    return (<ul>{props.todos.map(todo => (
            <li onClick={() => setSelectedTodo(todo.id)}>{todo.name}</li>)}
        </ul>);
}
```

I know for this specific usecase we could pass our `selectedTodo` through props and call our `useFetchTodoById(props.selectedTodo.id)` at the top of our component, but I'm just illustrating the issue with this pattern I ran into, we won't always have the luxury of receiving the dynamic data that we need in the props.

Also -- how would we apply this pattern for `POST/PUT/PATCH` requests which take dynamic data properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a basic `useFetch` hook the accepts a url, and fetches whenever the url changes:

```
const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!url) return;

    setIsFetching(true);
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => setData(response.data))
      .catch(error => setError(error.response.data))
      .finally(() => setFetching(false));
  }, [url]);

  return { data, isFetching, error };
};
```

Now you can create other custom hook from this basic hook:

```
const useFetchTodos = () => useFetch('api/todos');
```

And you can also make it respond to dynamic changes:

```
const useFetchTodoById = id => useFetch(`api/todos/${id}`);
```

And you can use it in the component, without wrapping it in `useEffect`:

```
export const TodoList = (props) => {
  const [selectedTodo, setSelectedTodo] = useState();
  
  const { data, isFetching, error } = useFetchTodoById(selectedTodo.id);

  return (
    <ul>{props.todos.map(todo => (
      <li onClick={() => setSelectedTodo(todo.id)}>{todo.name}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Comment: Ah so my misconception was that I assumed I need to rely on my useEffect to track the state change. Another question, how would you then handle POSTing new data to the api? for instance `useCreateTodo(newTodo)` - we can't just invoke it at the top of the component since our `newTodo` state will be undefined on mount, and wrapping the custom hook in an if is invalid.. The only other option then would be to wrap the if undefined check inside the body of the hook itself?

Comment: If no url you should avoid changing the state, and calling the API. In the `useEffect` check if the url doesn't exist `!url`, and return if that's the case. 
See updated answer.

Comment: Ah then, the same concept applies to my `useCreateTodo`. Thanks, you've been of great help!